# If $G$ is a finite group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and there is an element of $G/H$ of order $n$, then there is an element of $G$ of order $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> $G$ is a finite group, $H$ is a normal subgroup. There is an element in $G/H$ of order $n$. Prove that there is an element in $G$ of order $n$.

Note: I have proved that there exists an element in $G$, say $b$, such that $b^n=e$. I'm stuck in proving that $n$ is the smallest element, i.e. $n$ is the order of $b$.

Please provide a new proof if possible!

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Note: you can post me new methods of solving it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One can prove the following proposition (see below):

> If $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a normal subgroup then $\forall g\in G$, $o(gH)\mid o(g)$, where $o(g)$ denotes the order of $g$.

Suppose $o(g)=l$, $o(gH)=n.$ By using above proposition

$$n\mid l\Rightarrow \exists r\ , \space l=nr.$$

Now let $b:=g^r$ and suppose $o(b)=k$. We have

$$b=g^r\Rightarrow b^n=g^{nr}=g^l=e$$

$$\Rightarrow k\mid n \qquad(*)$$

On the other hand

$$b^k=e\Rightarrow g^{kr}=e\Rightarrow l\mid rk\Rightarrow rn\mid rk$$

$$\Rightarrow n\mid k \qquad(**)$$

By considering $(*)$ and $(**)$, $k=n$ is concluded.

---

*Proof of the proposition*:

Here's a slightly more general statement that might actually isolate the fact better.

> Let $f:G\rightarrow G^{\prime}$ be a homomorphism. Then the order of $f(g)$ divides the order of $g$.

In your case, you are just talking about the projection $f:G\rightarrow G/H$.

Suppose $o(g)=n$ and $o(f(g))=m$, so $g^n=e$ by cosidering that $f$ is homomorphism one can conclude:

$$f(g^n)=f(e)=e\Rightarrow (f(g))^n=e \Rightarrow m\mid n.$$

(**Reminder**: $g^k=e$ implies that the order of $g$ divides $k$.)

Comment: My answer is simple and @YACP 's answer is great. What is your problem with these answers?

Comment: @MAB you removed your comment, but I continued my answer and proved it. Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

If $gH$ has order $n$ we get $g^n\in H$. Let $t$ be the order of $g^n$. Then the order of $g$ is $nt$ (why?). In the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$ there exists an element of order $n$ (why?).

Comment: Why order of g is nt?

Answer (score 7):

Let $a\in G/H, |a|=n$ and $c\in G$ is a preimage of $a$. Then $[\langle c\rangle H:H]=n$. Since $\langle c\rangle H/H \cong \langle c\rangle/\langle c\rangle\cap H$ we have $|\langle c\rangle| =n|\langle c\rangle\cap H|$. Therefore the cyclic group $\langle c\rangle$ contains an element of order $n$.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on Isomorphism as yet!

Comment: I used so called Second isomorphism theorem, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Second_isomorphism_theorem

Answer (score -1):

o(g)/o(gH).Hence o(g)/n. i.e. o(g)=nt, for some positive integer t.
Now, o(g^t)=o(g)/GCD[t,o(g)]=nt/GCD[t,nt]=nt/t=n.
Hence our required element in G is g^r.